# Mindmup installation procedure

Tags: ruby, mindmapping

How can I install mindmup as a standalone application using sinatra. Is there any proper documentation for that. I don't have experience with ruby. Please help.

The source code is available  [here](https://github.com/mindmup/mindmup)

Comment: The readme has a section called [Running standalone](https://github.com/mindmup/mindmup#running-standalone). Did you try that?

Comment: Yes I did. I was not able to install it correctly. I was not able to find a proper documentation for that as well

Answer (score 0):

Note:  this is a lazy hack, not the official way, etc...

Didn't work for me either.  First it complained about `$` which is just jquery, so i copied and pasted jquery into `public/mm.js` at the end.  that solved that (not ideal, but who cares - technically, you should add another script dependency, etc...)

next, it tries to get external.js and external.css from static.mindmap.net which fails.   All I did for this is simply look in mindmup.com with the google F12 thing, then find the external.css and external.js in the sources :)  just dump these where the mm.js is.

It seems like the web.rb has the following

```
public_host = ENV['PUBLIC_HOST'] || 'http://static.mindmup.net'
```

so that's what was mucking everything up...  change that to localhost:5000 and don't forget to get rid of the timestamp variable:

```
static_ts = '20150106142106'
```

turn into

```
static_ts = ''
```

Now it complains about portrait.png, some font awsome stuff etc...  so we have to throw that in too.

and after all that, you still get an error, which really sucks...

so the code it's complaining in is actually the MM.main function!  Which i assume is the primary function!  It's some jquery thing where context is undefined... no clue how to go from here...